# map и undefined

Tags: javascript, массивы

Такой код

```js
x = new Array(5);
y = x.map((item) => item = 7);
console.log(y);
```

ничего не сделает(выведет 5 undefined);

не если задать массив через цикл то все ОК;

в чем проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` обходит массив **только по существующим** элементам.

В данном случае будет создан массив с 5 дырками. Поэтому применение `map`  здесь ничего не даст.

Кроме того, для *заполнения* массива, `map` использовать неверно. Вместо него, лучше использовать [`fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)

```js
x = new Array(5);
x.fill(7);
console.log(x);
```

---

Если же заполнять массив нужно не константным объектом, а зависящим, например, от индекса, можно воспользоваться функцией [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from?v=control)

```js
x = Array.from({
  length: 5
}, (el, index) => index);
console.log(x);
```

Comment: А я первый написал))

Comment: @Qwertiy, 10 секунд - не считается:P

Comment: можно повыделываться с новыми стандартами?) [...new Array(5)]

Answer (score 3):

Вообще-то во всём...

1. Присваивание аргументу функции ничего в массиве изменить в принципе не может.
2. На индексах, отсутствующих в массиве `map` не срабатывает. А у тебя все такие.
3. Надо использовать `fill`, а не `map`:

   ```js
   console.log(Array(5).fill(7))
   ```
4. Дело не в `undefined`:

   ```js
   console.log([undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined].map(x => 7))
   ```

Comment: @Grundy, поправил, теперь не выводится :) И этот комментарий надо было у вопроса писать, а не у ответа.